# The event order when add product to cart?

Tags: product, cart, event-observer, magento-1

When the customer adds a product to the cart, what is the list of events and the order of them?

Answer (score 3):

I had a quick look and I believe these events are dispatched after product has been added to the cart:

```
catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options
sales_quote_add_item (if it is a new item)
sales_quote_product_add_after
checkout_cart_product_add_after
checkout_cart_save_before
checkout_cart_save_after
checkout_cart_add_product_complete
```